# Macro Improvements

Tags: best-practices, programming

I am looking to simplify and improve on the code below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{test.txt}
a an and the this by on of
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter

\in@false
\def\upfirst#1#2\upfirst{%
   \in@{#1#2}{a and of that this}%
   \ifin@{\LARGE#1#2}\else {\Huge\MakeUppercase#1}{\LARGE#2 }\fi
}

\def\smallcaps#1\upfirst{\textsc{#1} }

\def\boldfirst#1#2\upfirst{\textbf{\uppercase{#1}}#2 }

\def\everytoken#1#2{%
\def\everytoken@##1{%
   \@tempcntb=0
   \@tfor \i :=##1  \do{\expandafter#2\i\upfirst   
  }}
\everytoken@{#1}%
}

\everytoken {{the} {battle} {and} {the} {resistance} {of} {france}}{\upfirst}

\everytoken {{Life} {death} {and} {the} {Universe}}{\smallcaps}

\everytoken {{The} {battle} {and} {the} {Resistance} }{\boldfirst}

\makeatother
\end{document}
```

What the code does it styles titles, by upper casing the first letter (if the word is not
in a bag of reserved words) or styles in smallcaps or bolds and uppercases the first letter.

[image]

I am looking for improvements in the interface (currently the title words must be enclosed in
braces) and for ways to input a file with the reserved words rather than just typing them in. (See the code around `in@`.

Comment: I can't write a full answer, as the question is rather vague. Maybe you could split it into several more specific questions? Anyway, your use of `\in@` seems questionable, as "an" for instance will also be found in your list. `\in@` just looks for a substring, it does not care for words.

Comment: Can we assume that spaces can be used as delimiters for 'words'? (BTW, in the demo I assume `\in@false` should be inside `\upfirst`.)

Comment: @StephanLehmke I am trying to find a way to say `everytoken{The battle}` rather than `everytoken{{The} {Battle}..}` and I am not happy in general with what I have done probably an l3 solution? Also to `input{bag of reserved words}` couldn't get the expansion right. You also right about the limitations of the `\in@` for example The must be capitalized if it is the first word but not in between.

Comment: @JosephWright `\in@false` is redundant because `\in@` sets either true or false.

Comment: @JosephWright `\in@false` your suggestion is good. Spaces can delimit words, but I am not sure about ending punctuation in a title (one can assume that it never ends in a word which is the bag of stop words).

Comment: @YiannisLazarides TBH, parsing with white space as delimiter is dangerous. For the input issue, try the `catchfile` package.

Comment: There seems to be a space missing in `\ifin@{\LARGE#1#2}`.

Comment: @cgnieder There are many things missing:)

Comment: @StephanLehmke Thanks, does not seem to expand within `\in@` neither the primitive `\@@input` does not give an error though.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides Nothing will expand in `\in@` because `\in@` doesn't expand its argument. In `latex.ltx` you can behold constructs like `\expandafter\in@\expandafter#1\expandafter{\version@list}`. As I said, you should not use `\in@` for this anyway.

Comment: @StephanLehmke Any suggestions what to use?

Comment: I don't know whether there is a ready-made macro for this (well surely there is...), but I'd just use `\do{a}\do{and}\do{of}\do{that}\do{this}` and define `\do` accordingly.

Comment: @StephanLehmke Will give it ago. Your suggestion is good to use Knuth type lists `\@elt`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Of course there's also a LaTeX3 version waiting. :)

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.dat}
that this
the
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,l3regex}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\everytoken}{O{}mm}
 {
  \group_begin:
  #1 % #1 are global formatting instructions
  \yiannis_everytoken:Nn #2 { #3 }
  \group_end:
 }

\seq_new:N \l__yiannis_words_seq
\seq_new:N \l__yiannis_final_seq
\seq_new:N \g_yiannis_reserved_words_seq
\tl_new:N \l__yiannis_first_word_tl
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_put_left:Nn { Nf }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \yiannis_everytoken:Nn #1 #2
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__yiannis_words_seq { ~ } { #2 }
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l__yiannis_words_seq \l__yiannis_first_word_tl
  \seq_clear:N \l__yiannis_final_seq
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l__yiannis_words_seq
   {
    \yiannis_if_reserved:nTF { ##1 } 
      { \seq_put_right:Nn \l__yiannis_final_seq { ##1 } }
      { \seq_put_right:Nn \l__yiannis_final_seq { #1 { ##1 } } }
   }
  \seq_put_left:Nf \l__yiannis_final_seq { \exp_args:NNV \exp_not:N #1 \l__yiannis_first_word_tl }
  \seq_use:Nnnn \l__yiannis_final_seq { ~ } { ~ } { ~ }
 }

\prg_new_conditional:Npnn \yiannis_if_reserved:n #1 { TF }
 {
  \seq_if_in:NnTF \g_yiannis_reserved_words_seq { #1 }
   { \prg_return_true: }
   { \prg_return_false: }
 }

%%% Simple version
\NewDocumentCommand{\Hugeupfirst}{m}
 {
  \tl_to_uppercase:n { { \Huge \tl_head:n { #1 } } }
  \tl_tail:n { #1 }
 }

%%% Complex but more robust version (uncomment the following four lines)
%\RenewDocumentCommand{\Hugeupfirst}{m}
% {
%  \yiannis_Hugeupfirst:n { #1 }
% }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \yiannis_hugeupfirst:n #1
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l__yiannis_temp_tl { #1 }
  \regex_replace_once:nnN
   { \A (.*? [A-Za-z]) }
   { \c{tl_to_uppercase:n} \cB\{ \cB\{ \c{Huge} \1 \cE\} \cE\} }
   \l__yiannis_temp_tl
  \tl_use:N \l__yiannis_temp_tl
 }
%%% end of more complex version

%%% Simple version
\NewDocumentCommand{\upfirst}{m}
 {
  \tl_to_uppercase:n { \tl_head:n { #1 } }
  \tl_tail:n { #1 }
 }

%%% Complex but more robust version (uncomment the following four lines)
%\RenewDocumentCommand{\upfirst}{m}
% {
%  \yiannis_upfirst:n { #1 }
% }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \yiannis_upfirst:n #1
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l__yiannis_temp_tl { #1 }
  \regex_replace_once:nnN
   { \A (.*? [A-Za-z]) }
   { \c{tl_to_uppercase:n} \cB\{ \1 \cE\} }
   \l__yiannis_temp_tl
  \tl_use:N \l__yiannis_temp_tl
 }
%%% end of more complex version

\NewDocumentCommand{\setreservedwords}{m}
 {
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   { \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_yiannis_reserved_words_seq { ##1 } }
 }

\ior_new:N \l_yiannis_input_ior
\NewDocumentCommand{\readreservedwords}{m}
 {
  \yiannis_read_reserved_words:n { #1 }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \yiannis_read_reserved_words:n #1
 {
  \ior_open:Nn \l_yiannis_input_ior { #1 }
  \tl_clear:N \l_tempa_tl
  \ior_map_inline:Nn \l_yiannis_input_ior
   {
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l_tempa_tl { ##1 ~ }
   }
  \seq_set_split:NnV \l_tempa_seq { ~ } \l_tempa_tl
  \seq_gconcat:NNN \g_yiannis_reserved_words_seq \l_tempa_seq \g_yiannis_reserved_words_seq
  \seq_gremove_all:Nn \g_yiannis_reserved_words_seq { }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\setreservedwords{a, and, of}
\readreservedwords{\jobname.dat}

\begin{document}

\everytoken{\Hugeupfirst}{The battle and the resistance of France}

\everytoken[\scshape]{\Hugeupfirst}{the battle and the resistance of france}

\everytoken[\scshape]{\upfirst}{the battle and the resistance of france}

\everytoken{\upfirst}{the battle and the resistance of france}

\end{document}
```

For adding to the list of reserved words you have two ways: either a comma separated list to feed as argument to `\setreservedwords` or a file where the separator is either a space or an end of line given as argument to `\readreservedwords`. You can use them in any order and each command adds to the list that is initially empty.

The syntax of `\everytoken` is

```
\everytoken[<global formatting>]{<first letter>}{<words>}
```

where

- `<global formatting>` is any set of formatting instructions to be applied to all letters (for instance, `\bfseries` or `\scshape`)
- `<first letter>` is the macro to be applied to the first letter of non reserved word and to the first word
- `<words>` is the list of words

I've given examples for `\Hugeupfirst` and `\upfirst` both in "easy" version (no accented characters) and "complex" one. With the "complex" version you can manage `\'equipe de secours` which you can't with the easy version.

[image]

Comment: In the regex you can use a single group `\A (.*? [A-Za-z])`.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch Yes, of course. Thanks. Feel free to add other improvements.

Comment: @egreg Pi\`ece de r\'esistance works, but Pièce de résistance swallows the accented characters. I guess the regex needs to be modified. Very good solution and a motivation for me to seriously look at l3 this year:)

Comment: I don't see the issue. However, the *caveat* is about the first character in the word: using there an accented character can give unpredictable results, unless the LICR form is used (`\'e` instead of `é`, for instance) and the RegEx version.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides To support `É` as a first character, maybe replace `[A-Za-z]` by `\cL.` in egreg's answer.  This will match a catcode-letter (`\cL`) token with any character code (`.`).  Perhaps `\c[LO].` (matching any letter or other token) is better.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch Thanks for the tip. The regex module is coming nicely now, great work. No chance for supporting unicode ranges I guess at this stage `[\uXXXX-uYYYY]`.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides Unicode support is only enabled in luatex and xetex (but currently broken)-: for pdftex, I would need to care about encoding conversion.  There is some plan to do that, but things are tricky, and it is intermingled with questions (currently discussed internally in the team) of what "text" is.  In principle, with xetex/luatex, `\regex_show:n { [\x{1234}-\x{ABCD}] }` should work.  In practice it doesn't.  This is very clearly a bug in `l3regex`.

Comment: Fixed on the repository.  This (Unicode ranges in LuaTeX and XeTeX) will work in the next CTAN release.  Otherwise, use egreg's xpatch (or is it regexpatch?) package to remove `\__regex_escape_loop:N` twice from the definition of `\__regex_escape_x_large:n`.  As a side note: one should be aware that we are not yet happy with the names of functions in `l3regex`, and they may change.  I will push for that to happen in one go, to ease the transition.  If possible old names may still be provided for some time.

Answer (score 11):

This reads the words from the files,, fixes the missing space in the in@ test  and avoids needing to brace each word.

The output isn't quite as you show as the version of the word list in the file includes `the`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{test.txt}
a an and the this by on of
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter

\newread\testtxt
\immediate\openin\testtxt test.txt

\immediate\read\testtxt to \foo 



\def\upfirst#1#2 {%
   \edef\tmp{\noexpand\in@{#1#2}{\foo}}\tmp%
   \ifin@{\LARGE#1#2 }\else {\Huge\MakeUppercase#1}{\LARGE#2 }\fi
}

\def\smallcaps#1 {\textsc{#1} }

\def\boldfirst#1#2 {\textbf{\uppercase{#1}}#2 }



\def\everytoken#1#2{\xeverytoken#2#1 \relax}

\def\xeverytoken#1#2 #3{%
#1#2
\ifx\relax#3%
\else
\expandafter\xeverytoken\expandafter#1%
\fi
#3}



\everytoken {the battle and the resistance of france}{\upfirst}

\everytoken {Life death and the Universe}{\smallcaps}

\everytoken {The battle and the Resistance}{\boldfirst}

\makeatother
\end{document}
```

---

To force the first word always to be processed change some of the macros a bit

```
\def\upfirst#1#2 {%
   \edef\tmp{\noexpand\in@{#1#2}{\foox}}\tmp%
   \ifin@{\LARGE#1#2 }\else {\Huge\MakeUppercase#1}{\LARGE#2 }\fi
}

\def\everytoken#1#2{%
\let\foox\@empty
\xeverytoken#2#1 \relax}

\def\xeverytoken#1#2 #3{%
#1#2
\let\foox\foo
\ifx\relax#3%
\else
\expandafter\xeverytoken\expandafter#1%
\fi
#3}
```

Comment: Thanks. The initial word (if it is in the bag of words is a problem) was thinking though of a simple solution, where the title is reprocessed and the first letter is capitalized for any word.

Comment: updated answer with one way of handling the first word